# Load views from a cloud service using a virtual path provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cloud-hosting, virtualpathprovider

Is it possible to use a virtual path provider to load views from a cloud service? For example if I have a site admin ui located under http://www.example.com/ui, I want to load the views from the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible by writing a [custom virtual path provider](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/28/mvc-3-razor-view-engine-without-a-controller/). So all you need to do in the overriden `Open` method is to fetch the contents of the view from the could service and return it as stream. For fetching resources over HTTP you could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.